# How to use T-SQL to filter a large set of data then work on the resulting groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm an SQL beginner. I'd like to brief the scenario before asking my exact question, just to lay out the right context.

I have a large table that contains a record for each time an electronic token is Created, Updated, or Closed. The primary key of the table is the "HistoryID", and each token has a TokenNo that is recycled at the start of the day (i.e. a single token with token number, say, 15 cannot be opened, closed and then reopened during the same day).

Below is a snapshot of the table. As you can see, Token No 940 is created (Status ID = 1), then updated to various statuses (2,3,4), and then closed (10). Later on, there are more records for 940 as it is opened on subsequent days.

```
╔═════════════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ History ID (PK) ║ Token ID ║ Status ID ║    Status Updated On    ║
╠═════════════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║           13435 ║      953 ║         1 ║ 2013-01-24 16:20:26.957 ║
║           13436 ║      940 ║         1 ║ 2013-01-24 16:20:22.090 ║
║           13437 ║      939 ║         3 ║ 2013-01-24 16:20:30.290 ║
║           13438 ║      939 ║         5 ║ 2013-01-24 16:21:07.387 ║
║           13439 ║      940 ║         2 ║ 2013-01-24 16:21:09.000 ║
║           13440 ║      940 ║         3 ║ 2013-01-24 16:23:14.510 ║
║           13441 ║      940 ║         4 ║ 2013-01-24 16:23:15.860 ║
║           13442 ║      940 ║        10 ║ 2013-01-24 16:23:30.013 ║
║           13443 ║      938 ║         2 ║ 2013-01-24 16:23:31.657 ║
╚═════════════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

I need to be able to group records together by the token they're associated with. The way I see it, this means I'll need to first filter the records by day, then I can filter the results by token number, giving me groups of records for each token number and per day. Then I can perform the calculations that I need to, such as averaging the time it takes to change from one status to another, or graphing the duration a token is kept open for.

I have no idea how to do this, and any help would be greatly appreciated. I would guess that such a problem is fairly straightforward for an experienced SQL developer?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need just `SELECT COUNT(HistoryID),  ... FROM  History GROUP BY TokenID, CAST(StatusUpdatedOn as DATE)` ...? I think you should add your desired result at least and also what you have tried so far.

Comment: I can recommend www.sqlzoo.net as an excellent beginner ->Intermediate SQL tutorial site. Best of luck.

Comment: LEAD() analytical function will be useful to calculate the difference in the times between status changes. this will give you the duration you need to avg, determine time open etc.  Min()/max() on the dates will give you the open and close times of each token (with the assumption being the earilest and latest times are the open and close.  If not we can figure that out using analytical functions and case statements.  However there's really no specific question here.  Provide some expected results and what you've tried and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a simple CTE or a common table expression to select the tokens for the day say today and then you can do the operations based on that CTE

```
with temp as 
   (
     select token id ,count(1) as cnt 
     from table 
     where status date = getdate()
     group by token id 
   )
 <do the operations here >
```

if the table is very huge CTE might be a little slower.In that case put the filtered results into a table like below

```
     select token id ,count(1) as cnt 
     into #temp
     from table 
     where status date = getdate()
     group by token id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(SELECT History ID, MAX(Token ID), MAX(Status ID), Status Updated On
FROM Table
GROUP BY History ID, Status Updated On)
/* Status Updated On looks like a DateTime, so if you're grouping by date 
you'll want to do CONVERT(DATE, Status Updated On) in the GROUP BY */

SELECT * FROM CTE1
/* Choose the calculations, aggregations or arithmetic operations you need 
to do here with CTE1. Important note, you are now selecting from 
CTE1.Column*/
```

Hope this was helpful or enough to help you get started!

EDIT: I reread your question and it looks like you're trying to group by token id instead of history id (I think?)

```
WITH CTE1
AS
(SELECT MAX(History ID), Token ID, MAX(Status ID), Status Updated On
FROM Table
GROUP BY Token ID, Status Updated On)

SELECT * FROM CTE1
```